# Variants of the 3-Partition problem

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, np-complete

[The 3-Partition problem (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) is a $\text{NP}$-complete problem which is to decide whether a given multiset of integers can be partitioned into triples that all have the same sum. It is well-known that the [3SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SAT#3-satisfiability) has a plenty of variants. Are there some variants of the 3-Partition problem discussed in the literature?

Comment: Did you try searching for any? You could immediately consider a variant where each integer occurs exactly or at most $k$ times, for some fixed $k$.

Comment: @Juho I searched and found little. Thanks for your hint. I would prefer to the variants *which have been considered* in the literature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One variant of 3-partition is the following distinct 3-partition problem, shown to be NP-complete in [1].

> **Distinct 3-partition**
>
> **Input:** A set $X = \{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{3n}\}$ of positive distinct integers, and a positive integer $B$ where $\Sigma_{i=1}^{3n} a_i = nB$, and $B/4 < a_i < B/2$, where $i \in [3n]$.
>
> **Question:** Is there a partition of $X$ into $n$ triples such that the elements in each triple sum to $B$?

The problem is also NP-complete when $B$ is bounded above by a polynomial in $n$. For an "application", a reduction from the problem is used in [2] to show a certain graph problem is hard.

---

[1] [H. Hulett, T.G. Will, G.J. Woeginger, Multigraph realizations of degree sequences: Maximization is easy, minimization is hard, Operations Research Letters 36 (2008) 594–596.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167637708000552)

[2] [Bonato, Anthony, Jeannette Janssen, and Elham Roshanbin. "Burning a graph is hard." arXiv preprint arXiv:1511.06774 (2015).](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06774.pdf)