# Strong NP-completeness of numerical perfect matching

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

This is a follow-up to post [Perfect matching problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/135843/perfect-matching-problem/135845#135845), where nir proved weak NP-completeness.

Suppose you are given two sets of integers $L$ and $M$ both having $N$ elements. We want to match each number in $L$ with a number in $M$. Such perfect matching has some cost given by $\sum_{i=1}^{N} l_i*m_i$.

The problem is to decide the existence of a perfect matching with some given cost $C$.

Is this problem strongly NP-complete?

Comment: Could you please clarify the cost measure? I interpret the current expression to always assign the same cost regardless of the perfect matching chosen, namely the cost of a perfect matching in which the $i$-th item in $L$ is paired with the $i$-th item in $M$, with the cost of each matched edge being the product of the two integers.

Comment: each item in $L$ is assigned one item in $M$ (such that the assignment is a perfect matching, or in other words, a bijection). Then they are multiplied together and summed. The indices refer to the perfect matching. That is, in order to do the "matching" we do a permutation on $L$ and $M$ so that the $i$'th elements in them are assigned together

Comment: @nirshahar Good interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I found an NP-complete problem, [Applying a permutation on a sequence with multiplication,](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/95939/) that reduces to my problem. The reduction produces an input to my problem where sequence $a_i$ is the set $L$, $M=\{1,2,3, ..., n\}$, and C=x.

This proves that the problem of numerical perfect matching is NP-complete for unbounded input integers.

**Update **
For polynomialy bounded input integers, numerical perfect matching problem can not be NP-complete unless RP=NP.

There is an easy reduction from my problem to [exact perfect matching problem](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/322307.322309) which in [RP](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02579206) (for polynomialy bounded edge weights) and there is no known deterministic polynomial time algorithm for it.

Exact perfect matching problem

Input: given edge weighted graph and integer w

Question: Is there a perfect matching of weight exactly w

References:

1. Papadimitriou, Yannakakis, The complexity of restricted spanning tree problems. Journal of the ACM 29(2), 285–309 (1982)
2. Mulmuley, Vazirani & Vazirani, Matching is as easy as matrix inversion. Combinatorica, volume 7, 105–113 (1987)

Answer (score 0):

**This is not correct**
It is left for educational value.

Another strong NP-completeness proof is a simple reduction from [distinct 3-partition](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22396) problem.

**Distinct 3-partition**

> **Input:** A set $X = \{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{3n}\}$ of positive distinct integers, and a positive integer $B$ where $\Sigma_{i=1}^{3n} a_i = nB$, and $B/4 < a_i < B/2$, where $1 \le i \le 3n$.
>
> **Question:** Is there a partition of $X$ into $n$ triples such that the elements in each triple sum to $B$?

The reduction:
$L$ is the set $X$, $M=\{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ..., i, i, i\}$ for $1 \le i \le n$, and $C=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}  i*B= B*n(n+1)/2$

Then the 3-parition instance has a solution if and only if numerical perfect matching has a solution.